# Decompressing a gz file in node js on AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a gz file stored in S3. I am trying to use pako to decompress the file. Here's the code that I have written:

```
s3.getObject({ Bucket:srcBucket, Key:decodedSrcKey }, function(err,data){
if (err){
    console.log('Error in getting object '+err);
}
else{
    try{
        var decompressedFile = pako.inflate(data.Body);
       }catch(err){
            console.log('ERROR in decompressing'+err);
        }
        console.log('Decompressed File'+decompressedFile);
}
});
```

There is no error that is displayed in logs. But the code never reaches the line where I try to decompress data using inflate function. I tried outputting data.Body and I got the following output, which looks correct:

Body: < Buffer 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 ec bd cd 92 ea c8 93 2f b8 d6 7d 0a ad fa 56 99 65 9e d6 37 b0 74 a4 48 29 12 29 82 0a 49 70 c8 4d ad a6 57 d7 6c cc c6 fa ... >

How do I uncompress the gz file stored in S3?

Comment: What makes you say it never reaches the line where you try to decompress?  And what line is that specifically?  If your getting the data I'm guessing its passing to pako fine but then halts?  I haven't used pako but we are doing something similar in a project.  Do you have to use pako?

Comment: I fixed some of your syntax and logic errors, try running the code again and see the output.

Comment: You are getting a byte buffer back and that's correct. See how you can save this data to the filesystem or just re-upload it back to S3 from the buffer.